# How to format IP into CIDR format for Control Access based on Network Location

Tags: azure, sharepoint, location, azure-active-directory, office365

I tried use [Control Access based on Network Location](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/control-access-based-on-network-location) to test my SharePoint Site but when i tried to enter my ip address in Enter IP addresses or ranges block, I am getting **Make sure the IP addresses and ranges are separated by commas, use CIDR notation, and don't overlap. Also make sure you allow your current IP address** error. 
They provided Examples: 172.16.0.0, 192.168.1.0/27, 2001:4898:80e8::0/48 as example and i have my ip and CIDR but i don't know what is 2001:4898:80e8::0/48?

Please help to rectify this error.

i have used 192.168.91.75/32 as ip ranges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is an IPv6 address range, you can use [online calculator](https://www.ultratools.com/tools/ipv6CIDRToRangeResult?ipAddress=2001%3A4898%3A80e8%3A%3A0%2F48&as_sfid=AAAAAAWKVvns6nkXXKi1O2IHO3hrDu-v_N3MzKNSIKAlRhCPZC95HaPAS9N1W7BAE3Pl1qEZt17XRjTWywWPyCbOJh5R9LWNwAYAnyfWfz4FcZvBFvxSkSOCp8QBmD1ZMvhlBv8%3D&as_fid=91bb5ec014750fcc799927b5fcc98c7303d27492) to figure details of the range:

```
Start Range: 2001:4898:80e8:0:0:0:0:0
End Range: 2001:4898:80e8:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff
No. of host: 1208925819614629174706176
```

the error you are having has nothing to do with it most likely (since this one is just an example, you probably didnt supply IPv6 address ranges, given that you dont know what they are). the error says your IP ranges overlap, and they cannot overlap. show the ranges you are passing to the conditional access policy or amend them if you can figure out how.

edit: after chatting we figured out OP was using internal IP address, instead of external.

Comment: thank you for reply but i am using only one IP address to test my case. So, should i use the IPV6 of same device for which i am using IPV4 and should it be in CIDR format?

Comment: i have used IPV4 CIDR but its showing same error message again.

Comment: can you show what IPv4 ranges you supplied? edit them into the question, please?

Comment: 192.168.91.75/32

Comment: so a single one? judging on your second question you should only put `192.168.91.75/32` and nothing else, also make sure you dont lock yourself out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205063/discussion-between-user9107307-and-4c74356b41).